# How can I update my LINQ query with search criteria to return matching records based on any single or combination of fields?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a LINQ query with multiple joins. The query returns 4 million records without a where clause. In the front end, I have several
search criteria for the users like this:

[image]

This is my LINQ query:

```cs
var transaction = (from sst in _Context.Transactions
                        join sstcnt in (
                            from ssti in _Context.TransactionItems
                            group ssti by ssti.TransactionId into g
                            select new { TransactionId = g.Key, NumItemId = g.Count() }
                        ) on sst.TransactionId equals sstcnt.TransactionId
                        join ssti in _Context.TransactionItems on sst.TransactionId equals ssti.TransactionId
                       where 
                              (ssti.TransactionId !=null && ssti.TransactionId.Equals(trans.TransactionId))||
                              (sst.EmailAddress !=null && sst.EmailAddress.Contains(trans.EmailAddress))||
                              (sst.Customer != null && sst.Customer.Contains(trans.Customer)) 

                              orderby sst.Created descending
                        select  new object[]
                        {
                               sst.TransactionId,
                               sst.Status,
                               sst.Created,
                               sst.StatusChangeDate,
                               sstcnt.NumItemId,
                               ssti.TransactionItemXml,
                               sst.Type
                        }
                        ).AsQueryable();
```

The search criteria can be NULL/empty or can be populated. I am filtering out the Transactions by using separate where conditions like this:

I tried putting && instead of OR

```cs
where 
    (ssti.TransactionId !=null && ssti.TransactionId.Equals(trans.TransactionId))||
    (sst.EmailAddress !=null && sst.EmailAddress.Contains(trans.EmailAddress))||
    (sst.Customer != null && sst.Customer.Contains(trans.Customer))
```

if I enter customer as "Jack" and email address as "test@test.com", I get the search records with name that matches "Jack" and everything else is ignored. By putting &&, I get 0 results.

How can I modify the query so that if the customer enters something in one field or several field, the search result should be based on if a match is found on any Single field or a combination of multiple fields. below is my sql query that is returning 1 row if I put name as "Jack" and email address as "test@test.com"

Comment: please provide test data and what output should be on each prompt